# How to Fetch The Friends List form facebook Who Uses Application in v2.5 for ios(objective C)

Tags: ios

How to Fetch The Friends List form ***facebook*** Who Uses Application in v2.5 for *ios(objective C)*

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yes,Done with following Code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-(void)getFbFriends
{
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends" parameters:@{@"fields" : @"name, picture"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"Fetched Result is :: %@",result);
             NSArray * friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
             NSLog(@"Friends List :::%@",friends);
         }
     }];

}